# Page wight with scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

Link: http://shahinlertour.com
I have problem with index page: bottom scroll. I want to remove it and fix page width like on other pages for example on http://shahinlertour.com/batumi-tour.html
Can't find what is the reason of this problem. Please help.

Comment: Please someone help it's very urgent...

Comment: Really nobody knows in what a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you could send a snippet of the css for the scrollbar that would help answer you question much better. However from what it seems based off the code it's coming from the offline tab at the bottom and played with the styling and had gotten it work while making the width 100% and margin 0, but again it would be easier to give a better answer with your code.

Comment: Did you find reason?

Comment: The only way i've seen it work is by taking the tab out all together. I would recommend not using twak.to or putting that functionality somewhere else in your webpage. This is also just the quick answer as it seems time is of the essence for you at the moment.

Comment: i removed tawk but problem still here.. I found that afrer removing our-foto div problem fixing...

Comment: It's very strange. Now not fixing when I remove this div.....What is it?